# Sqlalchemy and filter on relationship

Tags: python, filter, sqlalchemy, relationship

From the below code I've defined relations like this:

```
UnitTypeRowModel (self-referencing but only one in the doc)
  -- PlanPmDefinition (definition in the json doc)
    -- PlanPmValues (value in the json doc)
```

**The current result as json if I only have one plan_ou in the database table:**

```
[{
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": 1,
    "id": 4
}, {
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": 2,
    "plan_pm_id": 2,
    "id": 5
    "definition": {
        "id": 2,
        "tag": 0,
        "value": {
            "plan_pm_id": 2,
            "tag": 0,
            "plan_ou": 1
        }
    }
}]
```

**Code:**

```
class PlanPmValues(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'plan_pm_municipal_values'

    plan_pm_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    plan_ou = Column(Integer)  # Filter on this
    ...


class PlanPmDefinition(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'plan_pm_municipal_definition'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) -- always 0

    value = relationship(PlanPmValues,
               primaryjoin='and_(PlanPmDefinition.id==PlanPmValues.plan_pm_id, ' +
               'PlanPmDefinition.tag==PlanPmValues.tag)',
               foreign_keys='[PlanPmValues.plan_pm_id, PlanPmValues.tag]',
               lazy='joined', uselist=False)


class UnitTypeRowModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'unit_type_row_model'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': base_schema}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(base_schema + '.client.id'))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(base_schema + '.unit_type_row_model.id'), nullable=True)
    plan_pm_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)

    children = relationship(
             'UnitTypeRowModel',
             lazy='joined',
             join_depth=2,
             order_by="UnitTypeRowModel.sort_order")

    definition = relationship(
             'PlanPmDefinition',
             primaryjoin='and_(PlanPmDefinition.id==UnitTypeRowModel.plan_pm_id, ' +
             'PlanPmDefinition.tag==0)',
             foreign_keys='[UnitTypeRowModel.plan_pm_id]',
             lazy='joined',
             uselist=False)

    @staticmethod
    def get_for_unit(client_id, unit_id):
        db_session = DatabaseEngine.get_session()
        row_models = db_session.query(UnitTypeRowModel).\
            filter(UnitTypeRowModel.client_id == client_id).\
            order_by(UnitTypeRowModel.sort_order)
        json = util.Serialize.serialize_to_json(row_models)
        db_session.close()
        return json
```

How do I filter on `plan_ou` from the class `PlanPmValues` in the method `UnitTypeRowModel.get_for_unit`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom `ColumnPropery` for this.

```
from sqlalchemy import select, and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

class UnitTypeRowModel(Base):

    ...

    _ou_join = and_(plan_pm_id==PlanPmDefinition.id,
                    PlanPmDefinition.tag==PlanPmValues.tag,
                    plan_pm_id==PlanPmValues.plan_pm_id)

    plan_ou = column_property(select([PlanPmValues.plan_ou],
                                     whereclause=_ou_join).as_scalar())
```

I've broken `_ou_join` out as a separate property for readability only.

The way you have this defined in your SQLAlchemy code, you have a many-to-one relationship between `UnitTypeRowModel` and `PlanPmDefinition`; and you have a many-to-one relationship between `PlanPmDefinition` and `PlanPmValues`. I'm inferring that from the `uselist=False` arguments to both of those `relationship()` calls, and you may run into some other errors if you haven't enforced that in your database through the use of unique keys. That means that the resulting value can only return one row, which I've enforced using `as_scalar()`.

In general, you handle queries on related objects like this using [`association_proxy()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html). That's not ideal in this case because you already have and association object (`PlanPmDefinition`) between `UnitTypeRowModel` and `PlanPmValues`; that means that `association_proxy` would allow you to handle `PlanPmValue` objects directly from the `UnitTypeRowModel` class but not the `plan_ou` values.

Finally, you should always verify that you *need* to do this as an SQLAlchemy `Query.filter()`--that is, performing the querying and filtering on the SQL server--rather than doing it in Python via `filter()`. The former takes more time to code and test, but will almost always be faster because SQL servers are optimized for it; the latter takes less time to code and in practice only causes performance problems when you're doing lots of queries that return lots of results. Personally I write things in Python and then do the slow queries through SQL.

Comment: It should be a one to one actually. I should have left out `tag` or added it to the join too as it's actually always 0 and not used (not my doing though). I've updated the question to not use many to one (I hope). I also don't want a sub-query but a straight left outer join where the plan_ou must be set on the join clause and not the bottom where. I'll check out `association_proxy` some more.

Comment: To get your straight join without subqueries, you could map `UnitTypeRowModel` against the 3-table join. You're already doing that join every time you query `UnitTypeRowModel`, in fact, because of your `lazy=joined` keywords on your relationships. If you want to enforce read-only access from the `UnitTypeRowModel` class, I think you'd have to run them through a python property to prevent easy writing. Let me know if you want to see code for any of it and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes and I get it all as I want but what I want is to add a filter on plan_ou from the PlanPmValues-join when querying.